# Limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} x(\arctan(a^2x)-\arctan(ax))$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} x(\arctan(a^2x)-\arctan(ax))$ and I know the solution $\frac{a-1}{a^2}$, but I dont have any Idea, how to calculate this limit or at least how to start. Any idea?

Comment: Do you know what is $\lim_{x \to \infty} \arctan(x)$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Taylor expansions?

Comment: As long as I know $\pi/2$. Is there possibility, that it was an error in my solutions, which I get (only resoult without caluclation).  @user170231, how do u Solve with Taylor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that we are near $+\infty$.

If $ a=0 $, the limit is zero.

If $ a<0 $ the limit is$$+\infty(\frac{\pi}{2}-(-\frac{\pi}{2}))=+\infty$$

If $ a>0$, then we use the well-known identity, for $X>0 \;:$

$$\arctan(X)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(\frac 1X)$$

So, we want
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x\Bigl(\arctan(\frac{1}{ax})-\arctan(\frac{1}{a^2x})\Bigr)$$

we use the fact that, near $+\infty$
$$\arctan(\frac 1X)=\frac 1X(1+\epsilon(X))$$

thus
$$\arctan(\frac{1}{ax})-\arctan(\frac{1}{a^2x})=$$
$$\frac 1x(\frac 1a-\frac{1}{a^2})+\frac 1x\epsilon(x)$$

the limit is then
$$\frac 1a-\frac{1}{a^2}=\frac{a-1}{a^2}$$